# Nestjs: middleware for all routes except /auth

Tags: regex, typescript, routes, middleware, nestjs

I am started with nestjs recently and i want apply a middleware for all routes, except the auth route.

In the documentation it says that I can add all the controllers or paths of the routes where I want the middleware, but I find this way quite expensive

```
.forRoutes(
     SearchController,
     Other,
     Other,
     Other
);
```

So I would like to know if there is a solution, or if you managed to use regex for something like this:

```
.forRoutes(
    {path: 'All route except /auth', method: RequestMethod.ALL}
);
```

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted out ?  I can't seem to get exclude to work within an Azure function.

Answer (score 8):

Nowadays we use the function `exclude`.

```js
export class YourModule implements NestModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer
      .apply(YourMiddleware)
      .exclude('auth')
      .forRoutes('*');
  }
}
```

For further: https://docs.nestjs.com/middleware#excluding-routes

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for `/auth/login` in the version I'm dealing with (7.0.5), but using `.exclude('/auth/(.*)')` instead of `.exclude('auth')` seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 6):

DOC: https://docs.nestjs.com/middleware
TITLE: Excluding routes

```js
export class AppModule implements NestModule {
      configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
        consumer.apply(LoggerMiddleware).forRoutes('*')
        consumer.apply(tokenVerify).exclude('/auth').forRoutes('*')
    } }
```

Use `/auth/(.*)` in case you have routes like `/auth/login`, `/auth/register`, etc. .

Answer (score 2):

Exclude route referring exact route path.If you have define global prefix at `main.ts`,It's also need to come in to that exclude path.

Eg :

**main.ts**

```
app.setGlobalPrefix('api/v1');
```

**module.ts**

```
export class YourModule implements NestModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer
      .apply(YourMiddleware)
      .exclude({ path:'api/v1/auth',method: RequestMethod.ALL})
      .forRoutes('*');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment! this fixed my issue. Is this mentioned anywhere in the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to use fastify, bear in mind that it has a dependency on the latest version of https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp and therefore you need to use `(.*)` instead of `*`:

Link to NestJs updated documentation: https://docs.nestjs.com/middleware#route-wildcards

```
... .forRoutes('(.*)')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export class AppModule implements NestModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer
      .apply(YourMiddleware)
      .exclude('auth/(.*)')
      .forRoutes('*');
  }
}
```